# Date/Time conversion to local time

Tags: blackberry

See the below code

```
Date date1 = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(dateString);
int offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30").getRawOffset();
date1.setTime(date1.getTime() + offset);
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma";
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String dateNow = date.format(date1);
```

It converts fine to indian standard time in simulator.
When i try to use in device, the time remain unchanged.

Comment: Please provide an example 'dateString' value that you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
```

But what happen if i pass milliseconds to Date() function. 
It automatically gives date converting to user's local timezone. Cheers.

The below code have done everything fine.

```
 Date date1 = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse((String)kValue))
```

The date1 already converted to user's local timezone.

Answer (score 2):

[HttpDateParser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html).parse says in the docs:

> Parses a date string and returns the
>   number of milliseconds since January
>   1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

If you want to display the time in the device's own timezone, you don't need to do all that timezone conversion, just use SimpleDateFormat directly:

```
long timeSinceEpoch = HttpDateParser.parse(dateString);
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma";
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String dateNow = date.formatLocal(timeSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: Is the device timezone set to indian standard time?

Comment: Yes. Also for testing purpose, i am using GMT+5.50 for converting the time. It works fine in simulator but not work in device. I got the difference 5.30hrs between date & converted date in simulator. The code you provided, give the same date as source date.