# Timezone issue in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, timezone, date-format, timezone-offset

I am working on a project which requires me to create a Date value by setting it to a particular timezone .

I have used the following code

```
Date formatter1 = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2013-08-02 11:00:00"));
System.out.println("Date dd formatter1"+formatter1);
```

Result as follows:

```
Fri Aug 02 16:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2013
```

After parsing, it is giving me time according to device time zone ...
adding 5:30 automatically if device time zone is set to India Kolkata.

I want result to be as :

```
Fri Aug 02 11:00:00 Asia/Calcutta 2013
```

I mean it should not add the offset as reference to GMT .

How could I work upon this code to set the data required to me as per the Timezone and not change it internally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your original date string:

```
2013-08-02 11:00:00
```

does **not** include time zone information.  So, it is being interpreted as a GMT time.  Which then means that, displayed in Calcutta time, it will be

```
Fri Aug 02 16:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2013
```

You want to specify that `11:00` is **already** in Calcutta time.  To do that, use [one of the formats defined in the HttpDateParser documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

```
  // we make sure to specify time zone information "+05:30"!
  long timeSinceEpoch = HttpDateParser.parse("2013-08-02T11:00:00+05:30");

  Date date = new Date(timeSinceEpoch);
  System.out.println("Date: " + date);
  
  // use this to slightly change the date formatting ... same time zone
  String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma";
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
  String formattedDate = formatter.formatLocal(timeSinceEpoch);

  System.out.println("SimpleDateFormat: " + formattedDate);
```

**Note**: that in addition to adding `"+5:30"` to the time string, you have to replace a space after the date with a `'T'`.

This code will output:

> [0.0] Date: Fri Aug 02 11:00:00 Asia/Calcutta 2013
>
> [0.0] SimpleDateFormat: 2013-08-02 11:00am

if the device's time zone is actually set to Calcutta (Kolkata +5.5).

### References

Have a look [at this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627528/119114). 
[and maybe this one, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764512/119114).